# Restoring Windows Boot Sector/Hidden Partition after Dual Boot fail

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

A few months back, I attempted to dual boot my laptop with both Windows 10 and xUbuntu, to test out both and see which one I liked more. In the process, I believe I accidentally overrode the boot sector, and can only use xUbuntu now. After this process, according to gParted, there exists two "devices" on my laptop.

First, is a 27.25 GB device called /dev/nvme0n1. This device has two partitions, a boot partition, and one for xUbuntu itself.
Secondly, there's /dev/nvme1n1, which is 476.94 GBs and I believe is supposed to be Windows. I can't check though, since of course, I can't access it through file explorer.

I've tried a variety of steps and guides online over the course of many months but have not been able to fix it. I would prefer to not have to reset it, and would instead like to re-access Windows long enough to retrieve my files, and then perhaps switch to xUbuntu fully.

Rescatux fails to load for me, and I'm lost as to what other software could help me with my specific issue. If this thread didn't give enough information, let me know. I'm new to this forum so any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You can only fix Windows issues with Windows repair tools. And this is an Ubuntu question & answer site. But this report can help see what is where. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: You're right, my bad. If I have any more questions I'll ask a Windows forum. Thanks for the links.